# How can I have both the navigation bar and header on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get both my header and navigation links on the same line but with the navigation bar situated on the far right and the header in the center. I tried changing the width percentage of the nav and the h2 but that didn't seem to work. Much appreciate the help.

Here's my jfiddle to describe what I'm talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/as2wqwvy/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
<h2 class="headline"><a style="color:black;"   href="index.html">Name</a></h2>
  <nav>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="data.html">Data Stories</a></li>
    <li><a href="web_design.html">Web Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="resume.html">Résumé</a></li>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make: display:inline

```
.headline{
   display: inline;
}
.container-fluid nav {
   display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But right now the navigation is right next to "Name." How can I make the navigation right-align?

Comment: use
`.container-fluid nav { 
  display:inline; 
  float:right;
}`

Comment: So the nav bar goes right, but then "Name" become off-center. I tried directly targeting "headline" and making text-align center, but that doesn't work. Thoughts? Thank you again

Comment: What do you mean with center, do you want "Name" in the center? Then: `.container-fluid { text-align:center }`

Comment: I tired doing that beforehand, it doesn't seem to budge.

Comment: If I can't center it, my next option is to put "Name" left-align so on the far left but also on the same line. But then "Name" moves to the second line when it goes far left. 
    .headline {
  display: inline;
  float:left;

}

Comment: Never mind! I fixed it. I couldn't get "Name" center, but I was able to make "Name" become left-align and on the same line by making margin-right: 0px;